# NextGEN Gallery Template loading page twice.?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, loading, nextgen-gallery

I'm using NextGEN Galleryview template Wordpress plugin.

When I load the page, it first loads a very tall, blank document. Some 3000px in height.

Then this disappears and it loads the carousel with the correct height/elements.

I'd like it not to double-load, although I've not been able to identify where and how it occurs. I've compared it to another NextGEN gallery template (which loads properly) and FireBug shows them to have identical scripts/images, CSS and loading times.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

In the galleryview.css file there is this crucial bit:

```
 /* IMPORTANT - Change '#photos' to the ID of your 
    gallery list to prevent a flash of unstyled content */

    #photos{ visibility: hidden; }
```

Not sure why the default ID in the JS file isn't used here.

There is no ID for the gallery list in the JS file anyway, only a class. Changing the code to:

```
    #myGallery{ visibility: hidden; }
   .galleryview { visibility: hidden; }
```

Eliminates the flash of unstyled content. #myGallery is the actual ID, and changing its visibility seems to make the page load faster with no side effects, so I'm not pushing my luck. Leaving as is.

Hope this helps others. It took two days to solve this issue.